# Is it possible providing link in after before pseudo elements anyhow?

Tags: jquery, css, hyperlink, pseudo-element

I want to provide a hyperlink in after before pseudo elements. Is it possible with css or jquery?

Comment: No...psuedo-elements cannot contain HTML

Comment: Perhaps you might explain what it is you are **actually** trying to do?

Comment: Not posting this as an answer because @Lazar's answer basically says it all, but I just wanted to add that if you want to do it in jQuery, you can use the `.after()` or `.before()` methods to do it.

Answer (score 1):

To simply answer this, **no**.

This is because `:after` and `:before` are not a part of the DOM, and you cannot bind events to them or turn them info hyperlinks (that's not what they're made for anyway).

Depending on what you are trying to do, there might be some workarounds. For example, since you're offering to use jQuery, it means you can simple run a script to prepend/append an element to a selection, and add a link there. No need for pseudo-elements in that case.